# What's the meaning of three-phase reactive power of a three-phase device in balanced sinusoidal conditions?

Tags: power, ac, three-phase, reactive-power

I'm trying to make physical sense of the three-phase reactive power (a.k.a. total reactive power) for a three-terminal or four-terminal three-phase device (*e.g.* an AC motor, an AC generator, a load) in balanced sinusoidal steady-state conditions, whose mathematical equation as we know is \$Q_\text{T} = \sqrt{3} \, V_\text{L,rms} \, I_\text{L,rms} \sin{(\theta_{v \text{,} \phi \text{,a}} - \theta_{i \text{,} \phi \text{,a}})}\$.

The meaning of *single-phase reactive power* (a.k.a. *per-phase reactive power*) for a two-terminal network or device in sinusoidal steady-state is clear: its absolute value is the amplitude (maximum value) of the rate of flow of energy that oscillates between such network and the rest of the network. This is stated in page 4 of IEEE standard 1459-2010, and it can also be mathematically proven to be true.

The meaning of *three-phase active power* for a three-phase network or device (three-terminal or four-terminal) in steady-state (sinusoidal or not, balanced or not) is also clear: it's the average of the total flow of energy into the three-phase network (assuming the passive sign convention is satisfied), a negative value indicating such total flow of energy is actually out of the three-phase network.

However, the meaning of *three-phase reactive power* for a three-phase device is unclear to me, and unfortunately the IEEE std 1459 doesn't say it (defined on page 15). I mean, suppose a three-phase device is operating in balanced sinusoidal steady-state. Then, as we know the three-phase (or total) instantaneous power of such device is constant and equal to the three-phase active power: \$p_\text{T}(t) = P_\text{T} = \sqrt{3} \, V_\text{L,rms} \, I_\text{L,rms} \cos{(\theta_{v \text{,} \phi \text{,a}} - \theta_{i \text{,} \phi \text{,a}})}\$. So *total energy flow is never bidirectional, only unidirectional and at a constant rate*. So **shouldn't the total reactive power be zero in this case, since there's no total energy oscillating between source and load?** Yet it isn't as per the first equation. And **what does \$Q_\text{T}\$ in the first equation physically represent, then?** I'm okay if the explanation requires math.

I do understand that in each phase or leg of the three-phase device, the phase voltage and phase current waveforms are in general out of phase, and thus, there's a non-zero *single-phase reactive power* in each leg of the three-phase device. And since the device is balanced, each single-phase reactive power is the same. For this reason, it may make sense to then say the total/three-phase reactive power is three times the per-phase/single-phase reactive power. But wouldn't that be a fallacy, since there's no energy flowing back to the source (*which is what reactive power quantifies*), as shown in the second equation, so there's actually zero three-phase reactive power? Or is my logic wrong?

Comment: Your second formula for the total power (not active, not reactive), has no cosine in it, it's just the V*I terms. The cosine is for the active power, and the sine is for reactive (as in your 1st formula).

Comment: Nope. In balanced sinusoidal steady-state, the total instantaneous power of a three-phase network or device (three-terminal or four-terminal) is constant and equal to the total active power. A reference: Alexander & Sadiku's Fundamentals of Electric Circuits, section 12.7.

Comment: If by "total power (not active, not reactive)" you meant "total apparent power", then I agree with your first comment, although that's not what I meant in the question description. In my first comment, I assumed you meant total instantaneous power.

Comment: Just because it's balanced it doesn't mean the formulas are different. You can have a perfectly balanced system with perfect 90 deg currents, which means P=0 and S=Q. Similarly for P. And those formulas are derived in the same manner as in the usual case: S=VI, P=VIcos, Q=VIsin.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me, but I'll say the following. In a purely reactive three-phase device operating in balanced sinusoidal steady-state, since the total active power is zero, then the total instantaneous power is also zero. Check **[this](https://imgur.com/a/R1XtpX9)**, specifically the first plot of the second image (turquoise curve). The PF of the RC network is about 0.006, basically purely reactive. The second formula in my question description is correct.

Comment: Yes, and that is a particular case, the same way a purely resistive (balanced) load is the other particular case. All the other infinite possibilities are just your regular formulas. However, given the way the conversation went so far, I won't say more because it looks like there's a heavy packet drop on the way to each of us. :-)

Comment: Well, sorry. My point was that you were wrong telling me in your first comment that the total instantaneous power formula has no cosine factor.

Comment: What I meant was S, as opposed to p(t), but that's because I misread your question (you were right in your 3rd coment). I should probably delete these because they contribute with nothing to your question.